# ACPI error after battery ran out of charge

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, acpi

After running out of battery, starting my computer (DELL XPS 15, partitioned with Windows and Ubuntu) throws the following error:
https://ibb.co/gmSbCLQ
Instead of running Ubuntu, I get stuck in the initramfs console. If i ls /dev, I cannot see sda1.
I have tried booting with acpi=off, I have tried resetting BIOS to factory settings, I have tried choosing Windows at start up which also breaks with a failed automatic repair.
Any help would be appreciated. Cheers